# Python one hot vector encoding

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, theano

I'm trying to convert my categorical data to one hot vector with using python, preferably with numpy or theano. I don't want to use sklearn(I can not install it).

My data is like that:

```
data=[
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 1.],
[ 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 0., 2., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 1., 0., 1., 2., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 0., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 1.],
[ 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 0.],
]
```

My data have 7 columns and each column can have values 0,1, or 2. At end of operation I want to have one hot vector which will have 3^7-1 zeros and one 1 values.

I try to use

```
theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot(y, nb_class, dtype=None)
```

but did not work and I'm not sure if it is suitable for this task.

Most of the examples I see at internet suitable only for single column.

Comment: That is an odd way of doing one-hot encoding. Usually each column would represent one categorical feature. In which case you would have 7 * 3 one-hot encoded values. You are making one value for each combination of columns?

Comment: @DavidMaust, yes, I'm trying to represent each row with a one hot vector and each row can take 3^7 different values.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a built-in function for this, because you have to tell numpy/theano that your values can only be from {0,1,2}. 
Here is a simple numpy implementation, where
0000000 is mapped to 10...0,
1000000 is mapped to 01...0,
2222222 is mapped to 00...1.

```
data=[
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
[ 0., 2., 2., 0., 2., 0., 2.],
]
data_num = 7

one_hot_dat = np.zeros((data_num, 3**7))
# vector for making indices
vec = np.asarray([3**i for i in range(7)])
# compute the corresponding index for each data point
hot_idx = np.sum(np.asarray(data)*vec, axis=1).astype(int)
one_hot_dat[range(data_num), hot_idx] = 1
# one_hot_dat[0] should give the first data point in one-hot
```